# Using adjacent sibling CSS combinator (+) with HgClass and dynamic value

Tags: css, angular

I'm just trying to figure out if this is possible or if I need to rethink the way I'm going about things.

[Here's a very simple idea of where I'm at](http://plnkr.co/edit/08bS98kMipYi8VLULJiy?p=preview)

My main list will be constantly having items added and removed by other processes. I use `NgFor` to generate my items and I'm using the adjacent sibling combinator in my style sheet (`+`) to add `margin-top` to all but the first item, then `ngClass` to apply the class itself.
All god so far...

Now I want the value of `margin-top` to also be dynamic and linked to value coming in from another service.

So my question is just, can anyone give me a way of using the adjacent sibling selector and a dynamic value for the style it applies?

Comment: _coming in from another service_, what does that actually mean? ...How and what is it suppose to add to the existing code....

Comment: ...I'm also thinking, can't the _add and remove by other process_ simply pass elements with an inline style with the `margin-top` already in there, or with a predefined class?

Comment: It's just a variable. I want the value of my `margin-top` to be calculated by a service elsewhere in my application. I then want to apply it to all but the first item in my list. The more I read though the more I'm thinking I should just do this in the JS and skip the inevitable nightmare that always comes with trying to do things in CSS

Comment: Yes, I would suggest to do it like that since rendered CSS won't do variables cross browser yet

Comment: Could you let me know what is not working with the answer a gave, so I will be able to adjust and you to accept?

Comment: Sorry, I got round the issue in the end by restructuring the app and coming at it from a wholly different angle. I didn't get around to trying your approach but from running the example it does seem like it would have worked and it is an interesting approach so... have a tick. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since rendered CSS won't do variables cross browser yet, one option would be a small script adding a `style` like this

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  loadStyle(20);
  setTimeout(function() { loadStyle(40); }, 1000);
  setTimeout(function() { loadStyle(60); }, 2000);
})

function loadStyle(margin) {
  var node = document.querySelector('my-app style') || document.createElement("style");
  var css = ".my-item+.my-item{margin-top: "+margin+"px;}"
  node.type = 'text/css';
  if (node.styleSheet){
    node.styleSheet.cssText = css;
  } else {
    node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
  }
  document.querySelector('my-app').appendChild(node);
}
```

```css
.my-item{
  background-color: red;
}
.my-item+.my-item{
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<my-app>
  <div class='my-item'>A</div>
  <div class='my-item'>B</div>
  <div class='my-item'>C</div>
</my-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use style:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of userList" [ngClass]="'my-item'" [style.margin]="marginValue">{{user}}</div>

marginValue = '0 0 0 9px';
```